# How to do a port knock in objective-c/cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, sockets

How do I do a port knock in objective-c / cocoa?

For example, i'd want to 'knock' port 5000 by sending a SYN packet.

Comment: see [this](http://www.pcs.cnu.edu/~dgame/sockets/sockets.html).  if the connect succeeds, then you know someone opened the door.

Answer (score 1):

I can’t tell you exactly how, but it should be exactly the same as you’d do in C with a standard unix system. All C code is compatible with Objective-C, so any C examples you find should be just what you want.